# Error when to create migration and update database

Tags: database, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

For customize identity, I need to change context inheritance from `DbContext` to `IdentityDbContext` and I to add some properties to `IdentityUser`, I created two classes `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` and `ApplicationRole : IdentityRole` and fixed `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole>` but when I execute add migration command, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it is pretty impossible to read images. Why don't you just copy the error message text, the relevant code and add it to your question?. Use images of code or error text is not well accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

From the error image we can see the Entity Framework Tools is older than runtime 8.0.0, update the tools for the latest version.

Try to update your packages  to the latest version or 8.0.0+, like package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.